# MS SQL Server - storing many-to-many relations between several tables

Tags: sql-server, relationships

I have monitoring software that checks availability of some service on some host. Host can be included in many hostgroups and also services can be included in many servicegroups.

I have these tables to store both actual and historical (hosts and services that do not exist anymore) values:

```
CREATE TABLE hosts (
    id_host int
    name
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE service (
    id_service int
    name
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE hostgroups (
    id_hostgroup int,
    name
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE servicegroups (
    id_servicegroup int,
    name
    ...
)
```

Then, from many sources I learned that the best solution for many-to-many relations is to create relation tables. So I decided to create relation tables for relations that actually exist, as folowing:

```
CREATE TABLE host_service (
    id_host int,
    id_service int
)

CREATE TABLE host_hostgroup (
    id_host int,
    id_hostgroup int
)

CREATE TABLE host_service_servicegroup (
    id_host int,
    id_service int,
    id_servicegroup int
)
```

**Question 1:**
I'm not very skilled, so I'm not sure, if this is the best model that I can get. **Do somebody have other or better idea of how to store this kind of data?**

Next, I have table with measured data, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE monitoring (
    id_monitoring int,
    id_day int,
    id_host int,
    id_service int,
    value float
    ...
)
```

E.g. service "ping" on host "host123" was available for 90% on the day with specific id_day.
However, it is necessary to say for each of these rows in monitoring table in what hostgroup(s) was that host on that specific day and in what servicegroup(s) was that service on that day, if in any.

**Question 2:**
For me, they're very strange relations and I can't figure out how to store them into database, so e.g. two years from now I'll be able to say every group for every record in this table. Do somebody know the solution for my problem? I'd really really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1:  There is no better model.   Creating relationship tables is the right way to model many-to-many relationships such as you have.

That said, I don't think you need the host_service table.  You can find relationships between host and service in the host_service_servicegroup table.   Try to avoid creating more relationship tables than you need.

2:  If I understand your question, the way to handle this is to put start and end dates in your relationship tables.   So that as relationships change over time, you can look back in history and see what relationships existed on a certain day.

Comment: There are both host_service and host_service_servicegroup relations because yes, the relation host_service is the same in both tables, but not everything has to be in some group and some services can be in multiple groups. Although, it is possible to have nullable servicegroup part, this is what you meaned?

Comment: For second question, I didn't realize that I can manage it with time period for every relation record. Thank you! I will probably use this idea.

Comment: ServiceGroup can either be Nullable, or you can create an "All" or "None" ServiceGroup, if that makes more sense.